# How can arrows be added to faceted plots at different positions on each plot but at a constant angle?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a tricky one, and I'm making it trickier by basically asking two questions concurrently. But they're related (in practice, if not in theory).

## The issue

Basically I want to use one script and one data frame to create a faceted plot with arrows:

- at unique locations on each plot and
- at consistent angles regardless of the scale.

The goal is to use the arrows to indicate dosing of a therapeutic, which might change for individuals or treatment cohorts.

## Example dataset

Here's an example of the sort of data which I might need to plot with arrows:

```
df_3 <- tibble(
  ID = rep(1:2, each = 10),
  TIME = rep(1:10, times = 2),
  DV = c(runif(10), runif(10) * 5)
  )
```

## An example plot of what I DON'T want

The follow code generates an example of where I am, but not where I want to be:

```
ggplot(data = df_3, aes(x = TIME, y = DV)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = "free_y") +
  annotate("segment",
           x = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5), xend = c(0, 1, 2), y = 0.05, yend = 0,
           arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.20, "cm"), type = "closed"))
```

[image]

Note that the arrows can only be set to a single series of locations (which are tedious to add, since I need to finagle the x and xend variables to get the angle I want) and, because the y-axes are different, the angles of each set of angles is different.

For example, let's say I want arrows at times 0, 1, and 2 for Individual 1, but at times 2, 4, and 6 for Individual 2.

I'm thinking I need to add the location for the arrows into the dataset, but I'm worried that will force ggplot to plot the arrows for every individual plot, creating fuzzy/dark arrows.

I'm open to any and all suggestions or thoughts. I appreciate your time.

Comment: A goal of facetting is usually to compare e.g. what is mapped to `y` of different groups. Are you sure you want to set `scales = "free_y"`? If you'd set it to the (sensible) default `scales = "fixed"`, the curves would be more easily comparable, and the annotated arrows would all have a comparable angle (provided that `x-xend` and `y-yend` are kept constant). And if the scale of `y` is very different for different groups, you could perhaps add `scale_y_log10()`?

Comment: @scrameri, that's a fair point. This plot is really just to provide an example of the secondary issue here, where the arrows are not consistent between plots and need to be reset (ie new parameters entered) each time. In practice, this issue would arise not within one faceted plot, but between multiple, different plots. I'd like to find a solution that works across multiple plots without too much finagling each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that the arrows are totally defined in dataspace, which can skew the angle in visual space. One way to tackle it is to write your own geom that draws it exactly as you like, but that feels like overkill for a task that seems so simple.

This seems like a nice use case for Paul Murrell's [gggrid](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epaul/Reports/gggrid/gggrid.html) package. One of the possibilities is to create a function that takes the raw data and transformed data (called `coords`), and outputs the desired graphical object.

```r
# devtools::install_github("pmur002/gggrid")
library(ggplot2)
library(gggrid)
#> Loading required package: grid

df_3 <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:2, each = 10),
  TIME = rep(1:10, times = 2),
  DV = c(runif(10), runif(10) * 5)
)

arrows <- function(data, coords) {
  offset <- unit(4, "mm")
  segmentsGrob(
    x0 = unit(coords$x, "npc") + offset,
    x1 = unit(coords$x, "npc"),
    y0 = unit(coords$y, "npc") + offset,
    y1 = unit(coords$y, "npc"),
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm"), type = "closed"),
    gp = gpar(fill = "black")
  )
}

ggplot(data = df_3, aes(x = TIME, y = DV)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = "free_y") +
  grid_panel(data = data.frame(TIME = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5), DV = 0),
             grob = arrows)
```

[image]

The nice thing is that this is *not* a static annotation such as `annotation_custom()` which is simply repeated along facets. In the example below we can see that the second arrow gets send to the second panel.

```r
ggplot(data = df_3, aes(x = TIME, y = DV)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = "free_y") +
  grid_panel(data = data.frame(TIME = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5), 
                               DV = 0, ID = c(1, 2, 1)), # <- facet var
             grob = arrows)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This looks really useful, thanks. Unfortunately, while it works here, I can't get it to translate to my actual project (which means the example I provided was bad). Could you maybe explain why you need DV = 0 in the grid_panel?

When I run the code in my script, I get: `Error in unit(coords$y, "npc") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0`. Any ideas on what that means here?

Comment: The `DV = 0` is to set the y-position to 0. The error likely means that the function didn't receive y-coordinates. There might be a spelling error, or the mapping in the global call to `ggplot()` might not transfer properly to the grid panel.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether I fully understand what you are trying to achieve but one option to add your arrows would be to make use of `annotation_custom` instead of `annotate`.

```r
set.seed(123)

library(tibble)

df_3 <- tibble(
  ID = rep(1:2, each = 10),
  TIME = rep(1:10, times = 2),
  DV = c(runif(10), runif(10) * 5)
)

library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

segment <- segmentsGrob(x0 = unit(.05, "npc"), y0 = unit(.05, "npc"), 
                         x1 = unit(0, "npc"), y1 = unit(0, "npc"), 
                         arrow = arrow(angle = 45, length = unit(0.2, "cm"), type = "closed"), gp = gpar(fill = "black"))

ggplot(data = df_3, aes(x = TIME, y = DV)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, NA)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA)) +
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = "free_y") +
  lapply(0:2, function(xmin) {
    annotation_custom(grob = segment, xmin = xmin, ymin = 0, xmax = max(df_3$TIME) + xmin)  
  })
```

[image]

Comment: That's a clever solution to keep the arrows consistent, but does it allow me to use different locations for each set of arrows? For example, let's say the arrows for **1** are at times 0, 1, and 2, but for **2** are for 2, 6, and 10.

Comment: Unfortunately no. As explained by teunbrand in his answer, annotation_custom will add the grobs to each facet. Therefore I would go for the solution proposed by teunbrand which allows for adding the arrows at different positions per panel.